# use content of a file as subject with mailx in informatica PC

Tags: unix, email, informatica, mailx

I am using a mailx command in informatica powercenter command task. Requirement is to use the content of a file that gets generated with every workflow run, as subject of the email. Issue is subject is a sentence and my command captures only the first word in that sentence stopping at the space. How to overcome this? Is there an alternate way to achieve this?

Sample content of the subject file that gets generated is something like this:
testSub="Today is Saturday"

command used in the command task:

. /Targetdirectory/subject.txt; cat /Targetdirectory/Filename.txt |mailx -s $testsub xxx.zzz@gmail.com

When I receive the email, subject shows up as "Today"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put $testSub in quotes.

```
. /Targetdirectory/subject.txt; cat /Targetdirectory/Filename.txt |mailx -s "$testsub" xxx.zzz@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but when I executed the command task it failed with exit code 256. And of course with single quotes it prints '$testsub' (not it's value) as is.

Comment: Can you try escaping the quote characters like this \"

Comment: `. /Targetdirectory/subject.txt; cat /Targetdirectory/Filename.txt |mailx -s \"$testsub\" xxx.zzz@gmail.com`

Comment: Well it works fine for me. Double check the command. Take the command from workflow log and try running it in terminal

Comment: I tried the same command through command line. Actually nothing is happening. It neither sends the email nor throws an error.

Comment: Wondering if we can achieve this functionality in some other way. Is this doable with an email task?

Comment: Hey it finally works if we put the entire command in a shell script and execute in the command task

Comment: Actually I realized that there is a problem. This approach works only if I give absolute paths and values in the script. I will not be able to use my workflow variables. Guess back to square one:(

Comment: You could pass the subject line as a parameter to the script and access it using $1 inside the script.

Comment: Yes, actually I did that already and it works well. Thanks so much!